# Api gateway urls for AWS fargate containers

Tags: containers, aws-fargate

We are deploying our services in a containerized environment using AWS fargate. Our single Task has all the service definitions in it and is successfully deployed to the container.

We need urls to our deployed services in the containers for further processing. Is there a way by which we get api gateway to these containers ?

Comment: If you want just URL to access your service, you can create a load balancer to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks Arun , We are running multiple services inside a single fargate task. So do we need to create multiple load balancer for all the services.

Comment: one load balancer per service is convenient to setup. Unless you want to assign different ports of the load balancer to different services

Comment: For e.g you can assign `loadbalancer port 443  => Target Group 1 (Service 1)` `loadbalancer port 4443  => Target Group 2 (Service 2)`  . Then when you assign custom domain, it will `https://example.com:4443 => my-service1-elb-12345678.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can create URLs for your fargate services by creating Application load balancers.

https://itnext.io/run-your-containers-on-aws-fargate-c2d4f6a47fda

Comment: have you got it sorted?

Comment: Not Yet...
I am starting the service using ecs cli by issuing command  

`ecs-cli compose --project-name projectName  service up --target-group-arn targetarn --container-name app --container-port 8080 --create-log-groups --cluster-config jenkins --ecs-profile profile`


but here the target group is pointing to single container but I have multiple service in my task. Still not able to find how to expose all of them.